# UL tag - add class dependent on level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a Selectors which add classes to the UL Tag automatically (Even if the list contains more than 3 levels). I always need the level in which the UL tag is.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/somaberlin/9tgtwab2/)

```
$( "ul ul ul" ).addClass( "level-3" );
$( "ul ul" ).addClass( "level-2" );
```

But this adds UL to `<ul class="level-2 level-3"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using a selector, you could do this one at a time:

```
jQuery("ul").addClass(function() {
    var depth = jQuery(this).parents("ul").length;
    return "level-" + (depth + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

No need of using jQuery, you can use CSS.

```css
/* Level 1 */ 
ul {
  background: #333;
}

/* Level 2 */ 
ul ul {
  background: #CC00FF;
}

/* Level 3 */ 
ul ul ul {
  background: #FF00CC;
}

/* Level 4 */ 
ul ul ul ul {
  background: #CCFF00;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Level 1</a>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Level 2</a>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Level 3</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="">Level 3</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="">Level 3</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="">Level 3</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="">Level 3</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Level 2</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="">Level 2</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="">Level 2</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Level 1</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="">Level 1</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="">Level 1</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="">Level 1</a>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Level 2</a>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Level 3</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="">Level 3</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="">Level 3</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="">Level 3</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="">Level 3</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Level 2</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="">Level 2</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="">Level 2</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Level 1</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="">Level 1</a>

  </li>
</ul>
<span></span>
```

[**Demo:**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/9tgtwab2/1/)